# how do i make usestate wait for a response before updating its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm building an e-commerce store and I'm using firebase (firestore and Storage). The problem I'm having is that when I try to make a new product I gather the Form Data in a `useState` state and leave the `thumbnail` url property empty.

When I click on submit I publish the photo to firebase Storage and wait for the response that has the download link and then push the link to the new product use state and after that I would push the whole new product use state into the database. But what happens is that the thumbnail url always comes out empty and when I push the product in the database it's empty.

Here is the code

```
const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null); /*stores the image with all of its data */
const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = React.useState({
  title: "",
  brand: "",
  category: "",
  description: "",
  Offer: false,
  discountPercentage: 0,
  HotProduct: false,
  price: 0,
  stock: 0,
  rating: 0,
  thumbnail: "",
});

const add /* happens when i click submit*/ = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${newProduct.id}`);
  uploadBytes(imageRef, image).then(async (snapshot) => {
    console.log("uploaded");
    await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
      const path = url;
      setNewProduct((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [newProduct.thumbnail]: path,
        };
      });
    });
      
    setDoc(doc(db, "products", newProduct.id.toString()), newProduct);
  });
};

const handleInput /*happens when i change the form input*/ = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  if (event.target.type === "file") {
    setImage(event.target.files[0]);
  } else {
    setNewProduct((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        id: Data.length,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  }
};
```

The above code might be a bit messy because I tried a lot of stuff. I tried to make the whole uploading the image and getting the url then uploading the state to the database, which worked, but the `useState` hook doesn't wait before the code gets the download url.

It appears to work only then I push the new product object 2 times in a row into the data base (running the function twice).

Comment: `setNewProduct((prev) => { return { ...prev, thumbnail: path, }; });` would be better, no? You've got a lot of brackets in your state setters that I'm not sure belong there. You've got `[name]` in a later one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your post correctly, you are wanting to call `add` and fetch a thumbnail image asset to save into the `newProduct.thumbnail` property. You're on the right track using a functional state update, but the code is trying to use the current `newProduct.thumbnail` ***value*** as a dynamic property key in the `newProduct` state object. You'd really just want to set the `thumbnail` property directly. There's nothing dynamic at this part.

React state update functions are synchronous functions and you won't be able to access the updated `newProduct` state with the populated `thumbnail` property in the `add` function callback scope. The `setDoc` call should be moved to a `useEffect` hook with some dependencies that ensure that `newProduct` has both an `id` property ***and*** a `thumbnail` property.

```
const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = React.useState({
  id: 0,
  title: "",
  brand: "",
  category: "",
  description: "",
  Offer: false,
  discountPercentage: 0,
  HotProduct: false,
  price: 0,
  stock: 0,
  rating: 0,
  thumbnail: "",
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (newProduct.id && newProduct.thumbnail) {
    setDoc(doc(db, "products", newProduct.id.toString()), newProduct);
  }
}, [newProduct]);

const add = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${newProduct.id}`);

  uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
    .then((snapshot) => getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref))
    .then((path) => {
      setNewProduct((thumbnail) => ({
        ...prev,
        thumbnail,
      }));
    });
  });
};
```